# Does Google Cloud charge for Compute Engine instances during the startup or shutdown periods?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm referring to the periods when your startup and shutdown scripts are run (or not run if you don't have any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, google will charge you during the time the instance runs startup/shutdown scripts.

Any time the instance is running, you will be charged. The only time one is not charged is when the instance has the 'TERMINATED' status. If the instance disk is kept even though is terminated, the disk continues to generate charges as well.